# Does the ignoredFiles list accept wildcards?

Tags: filepond

Is something like this possible?

```
ignoredFiles: ['*.bak', 'temp*.dat']
```

I did not see anything in the documentation the mentions it on way or the other, and the example shows only "complete" non-wildcard filenames in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FilePond currently doesn't support wildcards in the `ignoredFiles` list.